# How can I Build a Unity3d Project to Run on a Web Page?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Before it was possible to build Unity3d projects to a unity web player, but today browsers no longer support it.  Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "_observe unity3d files_"?  Do you mean making a build for the web player?  Do you want to browse your project from a web browser?

Comment: @Foggzie exactly

Answer (score 3):

Use a WebGL build target, it generates a html that embeds the player

Comment: As a note: Build targets are installed when you install Unity so if the WebGL build target is not available in your *Build Settings* window, you can re-run the install and just select the "_WebGL Build Support_* check box during the "_Choose Components_" part (assuming you didn't move or rename your Unity installation).